# How does DetectChanges work?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

There is the following 2 entities, with the following properties:

```
Parent
    ID
    Children
Child
    ID
    ParentID
    Parent
```

Now I have the following code:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

var child1=new Child();
parent.Children.Add(child1);
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
parent.Children.Remove(child1);

var child2=new Child();
child2.Parent=parent;
child2.ParentID=parent.ID;
db.Children.add(child2);
```

At this point, child1 and child2 are completely identical. The Parent and ParentID properties have the same values (that of `parent`). Examining the dbContext `entry` for both of them also shows exactly the same information, e.g. OriginalValues is empty for both.

If I now call `db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` however, child1.Parent becomes null, while child2.Parent keeps its value. How does EF know to do this - where does it keep the info needed to be able to make this difference?

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 4):

In general

> Detect Changes works by detecting the differences between the current property values of the entity and the original property values that are stored in a snapshot when the entity was queried or attached.

[*Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)

and

> Ensures that ObjectStateEntry changes are synchronized with changes in all objects that are tracked by the ObjectStateManager.

[*ObjectContext.DetectChanges Method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detectchanges(v=vs.100).aspx)

so in your example after you disable change tracking the new values are on top of the original values until you decide to update the model by calling `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` and synchronize all objects (it more or less defers the operations). Now when you call `DetectChanges` all operations (`Remove` & `Add`) get *commited* to the model so that they can be saved later. Thus the parent is removed from the `child1` `parent.Children.Remove(child1)` and `child2` keeps its value because here the operation was to add the parent (assignment).

The reason why you would want to disable change tracking is performace:

> If you are tracking a lot of entities in your context and you call one of these methods many times in a loop, then you may get significant performance improvements by turning off detection of changes for the duration of the loop.

If you'd like to know the exact technical/implementation details you can digg through the source code:

[.NET Framework source code online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) > [**DetectChanges**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/ObjectStateManager.cs,25f6e3bb37bd53ac)

Comment: How does DetectChanges know what operations were performed? I can't see how this answers the question.